# mapply runs into endless loop

Tags: r, mapply

I have a data.table like this:

```
testDT <- data.table(SFf = as.character(c("C1H1", "C3H4Cl")),
                     Mult = as.integer(c(3,5))
)
```

now I am trying to loop over the rows of this table and apply a function (multiform() from the package enviPat) to it like this:

```
mapply(multiform,testDT$SFf,testDT$Mult)
```

the output of it should be two strings, namely "C3H3" and "C15H20Cl5". However the function simply never stops calculating and seems to get caught up in an endless loop.

When I apply the function like

```
multiform("C1H1",3)
```

it works and I get "C3H3" as output. What am I doing wrong?

Yasel

Comment: Probably you are doing nothing wrong, the function `multiform` is just really slow. Looking at it's [code](https://github.com/cran/enviPat/blob/master/R/multiform.R) it seems totally plausible that it could take a very, very long time on even moderately sized inputs.

Comment: when I am using it only once it takes much less than a second. but when I tried it for two rows via mapply I stopped it after 10 min, so I think that canot be it

Comment: It's taking time because of the second SFf value. If you do this `multiform("C3H4Cl",5)`, it will also take too long.

Comment: If it's taking too long on only 2 elements, then yes, probably something is specifically awry with the code that handles that particular case.

Comment: You're right, it does end up in an infinite loop for that particular example. I don't know enough about chemical formulas to debug it effectively, but it is likely that this is a bug in the function. I would contact the package authors about it and show them this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. The problem was that the function multiform() does not allow elements without numbers behind them. 
So it wont take "C3H4Cl" but "C3H4Cl1".

I don't think that this is intended and will try to contact the authors of the package.

Comment: I think they're aware. The "Details" section in this function's documentation says "Chemical formulas must conform to what is described in check_chemform". If you run `data(isotopes); check_chemform(isotopes, 'C3H4Cl')`, it will show you the corrected formula (with a 1 on the end).